# Generate sound waves while using Web-Speech-api

Tags: javascript

I am using web-speech-api, i want to generate sound waves while speaking in mic by using JavaScript. for instance, just like in Siri (Apple) when you speak, it generates waves. will appreciate your suggestions or ideas.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is about technical problems about programming, not debating and giving opinions. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: https://wavesurfer-js.org/plugins/microphone.html

Comment: Right Cid, i will follow the rules and  Thank you soo much Shifty Thomas